# Replace a part of a string with a shell variable's expansion

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My goal is to replace all "special" strings from text file and replacing them with system variables. For example as input would be line like this one:

```
__HOME__/properties/common/file.properties
```

Here the special string is __HOME__ and I should replace it with the system $HOME variable. As output it should be:

```
/home/user/properties/common/file.properties
```

I was trying to resolve this problem with `sed` command and I came to this point:

```
echo __HOME__/properties/common/file.properties | sed -e 's/\(__\)\([A-Z]*\)\(__\)/\2/g'
```

As output i get `HOME/properties/common/file.properties` which is wrong. I was trying to replace the back reference from `sed` (here `\2`) with something like `echo \2` but this is not going to work. Is there anything which could be done in Bash?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to write a generic code that can substitute any variable? I'm not sure whether `sed` can do that. It could be programmed in Bash with some effort and probably much cleaner in a more powerful language like Python. For security reasons, I'd recommend you explicitly list the variables that can be expanded anyway, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use perl

```
perl -lpe 's/__(.+?)__/$ENV{$1}/g' file
```

Just checks for strings which have `__something__` and replaces them with the environment variable from your shell.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` for this:

```
s='__HOME__/properties/common/file.properties'
eval "printf '%s\n' "$(sed 's/__\([A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)__/$\1/g' <<< "$s")""

/home/user111/properties/common/file.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

We can further simplify this process by using a different separator for `sed` expression - I have used `#` instead of `/`:

```
path='__HOME__/properties/common/file.properties'
sed "s#__HOME__#$HOME#" <<< "$path"
# output => /Users/codeforester/properties/common/file.properties
```

Since the `sed` expression is wrapped in double quotes, it does expand `$HOME` and slashes in the `$HOME` expansion wouldn't upset the `sed` expression because we are using `#` as the separator. Any character could be chosen as the separator so long as it doesn't occur in any other part of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Could use Python**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\_.*\_)"

test_str = "__HOME__/properties/common/file.properties"

subst = "/home/potato"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

**Result:**

```
/home/potato/properties/common/file.properties
```